# Not MONEY but GIFT alphametic

Tags: lateral-thinking, no-computers, alphametic

There is a well-known alphametic story where a poor college student sends a telegram with the words "SEND MORE MONEY" to his parents, asking for more money, and asking to fill in each letter with a different digit in order to figure out how much he is asking for. 
In another alphametic story the same poor college student sends a telegram with the words "SEND A GIFT":

```
     SEND = A * GIFT
```

The parents send him a gift. Although the gift is odd and what the parents send is odd and everything related is odd, the poor college student is happy with it.

**Which digit does each letter represent?** 
(Please present the full analysis how these digits can be determined. Every letter stands for a digit in base-10 representation, different letters stand for different digits, and leading digits are always non-zero.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

> There are 15 possible solutions:
>  $4827 = 3 * 1609$
>  $5427 = 3 * 1809$
>  $8463 = 7 * 1209$
>  $9706 = 2 * 4853$
>  $3690 = 2 * 1845$
>  $6970 = 2 * 3485$
>  $7690 = 2 * 3845$
>  $9630 = 2 * 4815$
>  $9670 = 2 * 4835$
>  $9730 = 2 * 4865$
>  $9370 = 2 * 4685$
>  $7852 = 4 * 1963$
>  $7236 = 4 * 1809$
>  $8316 = 4 * 2079$
>  $7854 = 6 * 1309$

Starting point

> "The gift is odd". This is the [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) part.
>  It means the amount is an odd number.
>  So we conclude T has to be odd digit.
>  
>  $A$ and $T$ obviously can not be $1$
>  Since $A >=2$ then $G <=4$
>  
>  Also A cannot be 5 since it will result in $D = 5$
>  Also A cannot be 9 because it will result in $S = 9$ or go over 4 digits in the result
>  So A can be one of [2,3,4,6,7,8]

[EDIT]

> As Trenin pointed out A can also be even. In my original answer I handled A as odd, that's why the cases are handled in this way..A odd then A even.

now start filling in the blanks using the values we already know

Case 1:

> A = 3, T = 7.  We immediately see that $G =2$ (otherwise we get to $S = 9$ or go over 4 digits).
>  The carriage from $3*I + carriage from 3*f + 2$ should be one of [0,2,3] (otherwise we get S = 7 or we go over 4 digits).  But 3 cannot be achieved since we cannot get the carriage from 3*f to be 3.
>  The carriage can be 0 only if $I = 0$ (it cannot be 2 or 3 because they are already taken).  We have in this case 
>
>       20F7 * 3 = 6EN1
>  F cannot be 4 because it will result in N being 4, F cannot be 5 or 9 since it will result in N being 7 (already taken), F cannot be 8 since it will result in E = 2 (already taken).
>  So no valid solution here.
>  The carriage can be 2 only if I is [6,8,9].
>  Trying every combination for I = 6 and F any available digit gets us to conflicts every time.
>
>  **Conclusion $A = 3, T = 7$ - not possible**

Case 2.

> A = 3, T = 9.
>  We get G is one of [1,2]
>  Considering G = 1.
>  1IF9 * 3 = SEN7.
>  Considering F = 0 we get 1I09 * 3 = SE27.
>  Possible values for I are [4,5,6,8].
>  Doing the math for all possible values we get 2 matches. I one of [6,8]
>  **This results in 2 possible solutions:**
>  $4827 = 3 *1609$   and $5427 = 3 * 1809$
>
>  For G = 2 we end up with F being one of [6,8].
>  For F = 6 there is no possible value for I. (we end up with an already used value for E).
>  For F = 8 There is no possible value for I.
>
>   **Conclusion: No other possible values that what we found above**

Case 3:

> A = 7, T = 3. This results in G = 1.
>  Starting with F = 0 we get no valid value for I.
>  For F = 2 again no valid value for I.
>  Going through all the possible values of F ([4,5,6,8,9]) we get the same result. Nothing valid for I.
>
>  **Conclusion: this doesn't work**

Case 4:

> A = 7, T = 9. We see immediately that G = 1.
>  Trying with F one of [0,2,3,4,5,6,8] and following the same process as for the other cases (got lazy here so I won't list all the possible outcomes) we end up with the one solution for F = 0.
>
>   **$8463 = 7 * 1209$**

**[EDIT]** After Trenin's comment.

> In case A and SEND can be even numbers, in addition to the cases above we get:

Case 5.1:

> A = 2, T = 3 => G can be only 4 (for 1,2,3 we get duplicate digits).
>  in this case F can be one of [5,8,9].
>  IN this case we get only one valid value $9706 = 2 * $4853$

Case 5.2:

> A =2, T = 5 => G can be 1, 3 or 4. otherwise we get conflicts in the digits.
>  Starting with G = 1. We get the possible values for F [3,4,6,7,8,9].
>  Calculating step by step we end up with these solutions:
>  $3690 = 2 * 1845$
>  continuing with G = 3 we get the possible values for F [4,6,8]
>  Doing the math for all of them we get:
>  $6970 = 2 * 3485$
>  $7690 = 2 * 3845$
>  for G = 4 we get the possible values for F [1,3,6,8].
>  Doing the math we get
>  $9630 = 2 * 4815$
>  $9670 = 2 * 4835$
>  $9730 = 2 * 4865$
>  $9370 = 2 * 4685$

Case 5.3

> A = 2, T = 7. Results in G being 1 or 3.
>  Doing the same steps as above, calculating the possible values for F and then filling in the missing value for I we get no valid results.

Case 5.4

> A = 4, T = 3. Results in G being 1 or 2.
>  Doing the same steps as above, calculating the possible values for F and filling in the missing value for I we get one valid result:
>  $7852 = 4*1963$

Case 5.5 to 5.15 (got tired of typing )

> A = 4, T = 5 gives no valid result
>  A = 4, T = 7 no results again
>  A = 4, T = 9 gives out
>  $7236 = 4 * 1809$
>  $8316 = 4 * 2079$
>  Starting A = 6 and further is even easier since G can be only 1.
>  A = 6, T = 3 => nothing
>  A = 6, T = 5 => nothing
>  A = 6, T = 7 => nothing
>  A = 6, T = 9 we get:
>  $7854 = 6 * 1309$
>  A = 8, T = 3 => nothing
>  A = 8, T = 5 => nothing
>  A = 8, T = 7 => nothing
>  A = 8, T = 5 => nothing

Comment: Why does $A$ have to be odd?  The clue is only that the gift is odd.  If the clue was that the sending of the gift was odd, then I would conclude $SEND$ is odd and agree that both $T,A,D$ are all odd.  But from the clue, I don't think you can infer $A$ is odd, but only $GIFT$ and thus only $T$ is odd.

Comment: @Trenin. Hmmm...you might be right on this. I saw the word `odd` and got all fired up. Anyway, the solutions I found are still valid. I will start digging for the other solutions as well. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Trenin. Fixed it. Thanks again for the tip. I would split the points with you on this if I could :).